# Windows c++ simulate click admin

Tags: c++, click, simulate

I have a program in Qt5 Windows 10 where I simulate clicks (to help a friend with a disability with a special device). I use SendInput. The problem is that when I simulate a click to press a key on the Windows Virutal Keyboard (osk.exe), it does not work. In fact, it works but only if I run the program as administrator. However, I would like it to work even when the program is not run as admin.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you absolutely need it to run under restricted privileges?

Comment: Looks like you gotta have to be an admin to run this, so, there is probably no other solution other than running this with administrator privileges.

Comment: @Ceros Because I want the program to be used by other people who don't have admin rights on their computer.

Comment: Do you have to use SendInput?

Comment: @picklechips No I can use anything that works on Windows with Qt

Answer (score 0):

Qt has everything you need in order to simulate input, so you don't need to use `SendInput`

First, create a `QMouseEvent` and then call `QCoreApplication::postEvent`

The implementation would depend on what exactly you want to simulate, but your code would look something like this:

```
// Pos is the position of the click
QMouseEvent *me = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);

QCoreApplication::postEvent(reciever, me); // Where reciever is a QObject handling the event
```

**EDIT**: Another snippet worth trying:

```
#include <windows.h>

QApplication::desktop()->cursor().setPos(globalX,globalY);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I will try that. You think it will work even if the program is not running as admin ?

Comment: As far as I am aware this doesn't require admin rights.

Comment: I've just realized this might not work since the windows virtual keyboard is an external app. Worth a try, however.

Comment: Thanks. The admin rights are not to use SendInput but rather for being able to click on the Windows Virtual Keyboard (osk.exe). Anyway I will try it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think I already tried QMouseEvents but I was only able to click in Qt windows but not in orhter windows.

Comment: How are you running the virtual Keyboard? If you attach it to a QProcess you could send that in as the `reciever` argument in `postEvent`

Comment: I run the virtual keyboard normally by going in Start / osk.exe  or by simply calling a command to launch osk.exe

Comment: I just added another snippet you could try. Do you just need a mouse click in a specific (x, y) position?

Comment: Yes, its a specific mouse click a a given x,y position.
I will try your code, thanks.

Comment: It's the same thing. It works if I run it as admin but it does not otherwise. I think the virtual keyboard might have a protection against it or that my program should work at a higher level (like when I run it as admin) to be able to click.

Comment: Interesting. I'm afraid I can't be of any help then. Is there a reason you need to simulate a click on the keyboard rather than just simulate a keypress?

Comment: Yes, I must use the virtual keyboard because he has to choose the letters himself. I might have something here:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?337002-How-to-Send-Mouse-Event-to-Anothther-Window

It says that SendInput gets filtered by the keyboard. But maybe another method would work for instance SendMessage. However, my abilities to understand this are limited.

Comment: After a quick google search you're definitely not the only one who's come across this issue, and it looks like osk.exe has some sort of protection on it. Might be worth looking at a 3rd party virtual keyboard.

https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA727CA729&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=osk.exe+simulate+click&*

Comment: Ok thanks, I searched but I didn't find anything yet. If I can make it work by running as admin I guess I should be able without running admin too...I don't see why there is such a protection if I can bypass it by running as admin...